# Java format Number/Amount to

Tags: java, jasper-reports, string-formatting, ireport

I would like to format an amount : the required format is : #.##0,00
example : 299.552.698,05 or 299.552.698,00

When I try to use

```
  (new DecimalFormat("#.##0,00")).format($F{amount}.doubleValue())
```

It causes an exception and whan I try to use :

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format($F{amount}.doubleValue())
```

I have the symbole of the currency which I don't want to print.

Comment: It might help if you told us what exception is thrown.

Comment: Doesn't look like Java... what the $F{ ???

Comment: $F becuase I'm writing code in iReport. the exception is IllegaLArgumentexception. for : "#.##0,00" .

Answer (score 3):

`"#.##0,00"` is an invalid format string.

The comma, and *only* the comma, is the grouping character, but it is *localized*, meaning if you set the Locale, you'll get the appropriate separator for your locale.

If you prefer the "one-line hack" way, this will work:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{amount}.doubleValue()).replace(",", "x").replace(".", ",").replace("x", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use the DecimalFormatSymbols class to trick the formatter, like this:

```
public String formatNumber(double value) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    return formatter.format(value);
}
```

hope it works for you...

Comment: You can send the date preformatted amount variable to your report. The formatting can be done by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
return (new DecimalFormat("#.##0,00", symbols)).format($F{amount}.doubleValue());
```

Check out the two argument constructor for [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)